# Cache View in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I understand that we can cache an action or view page in CakePHP 2.0. Refer to this link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Cache');
}

public $cacheAction = array(
    'view' => 36000,
    'index' => 48000
);
```

However, it seems that CakePHP 3.0 has removed helper(http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html). Is there any other way in CakePHP 3.0 I can cache the view page. For example, I have a index view/action. And I would like to cache that page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way in CakePHP 3.0 I can cache the view page.

Not without developing something yourself. Like for example saving the rendered content to a file in callback for `Dispatcher.afterDispatch` event and then checking for the file in callback for `Dispatcher.beforeDispatch` event and returning the cached response.

Better to use you something like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) which is more suited for the job.

Comment: Thanks ADmad. Do you have any tutorial for CakePHP 3.0 and Varnish? I just want to make sure I do it in the most efficient manner.

Comment: Follow any generic Varnish tutorial. You don't require any special changes in CakePHP to use it.